# Delete column from database

Tags: java, database

I have a database with so many values.How can i delete a specified row using a query.

I am using following query for deletion.I want to delete a row whith the help of colum name=user_name.(user_name=example).

But example named row is not present at the table.is shows error.Any `if exist` query for this

```
 preparedStatement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM users  WHERE IF EXISTS user_name=example");
         preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

The following error occur when i trying to compile

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXISTS user_name='example'' at line 1
```

Comment: remove `IF EXISTS`, use `user_name='example'` (with quotes) and use `preparedStatement.executeUpdate()`. it shouldnt throw any error even if no result

Comment: You don't need "if exists" here.

Comment: Which error does it show?

Comment: Your title says you want to delete a `column`, you question talks about deleting a row. what is it you want exactly? If you just want to delete all users that have a certain user_name, please says so :)

Comment: i want to delete a row by the help of a column name.Here i want to delete example column value contained row

Answer (score 4):

- remove `IF EXISTS`
- use `user_name='example'` (with quotes) or even better `user_name=?` with PreparedStatement
- use `preparedStatement.executeUpdate()`

**it shouldnt throw any error even if no result**

Comment: TecHunter...i know this code...It will not work when `'example'` is not containing in the database column.Then i try `IF EXISTS`

Comment: @DeepuKrishna then show me the error you have with this one. by column you mean row?

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXISTS user_name=''example' at line 1

Comment: @DeepuKrishna no, I mean using the simple `DELETE FROM users WHERE user_name='example'`. and from your query there I can see you use double quotes along with simple quotes. Please try again the simple query exactly like mine

Comment: What do you mean with "It will not work when 'example' is not containing in the database column.Then i try IF EXISTS" What exactly is "does not work" before you put in the "if exists"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot the apostrophs that span the String literal 'example':

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE user_name='example'.
```

The 'WHERE EXISTS' is unnecessary here!

Greetings

Christopher

Comment: Christopher Stock...i know this code...It will not work when `'example'` is not containing in the database column.Then i try `IF EXISTS`

Answer (score 0):

I tried here in my computer this way and works fine

```
PreparedStatement pt =con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM users  WHERE IF EXISTS user_name='"+"example'");
pt.executeUpdate();
```

I made a temporary table and run it

Comment: I can't see how this can work with your quotes... it compiles as `user_name=''example`

Comment: @TecHunter i just did not copy from code to here.So misplaced ' here in the answer

Comment: @DeepuKrishna if you can not find the small error in it then it is understood how good you are in java

Comment: it shows an error

`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXISTS user_name=''example' at line 1`

Comment: i dont want to split the string